# How can I encrypt JWT Token in Web Api C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

My Jwt Token looks like below:

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9leGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxMzU2OTk5NTI0LCJuYmYiOjEzNTcwMDAwMDAsImV4cCI6MTQwNzAxOTYyOSwianRpIjoiaWQxMjM0NTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvZXhhbXBsZS5jb21cL3JlZ2lzdGVyIiwidGVzdC10eXBlIjoiZm9vIn0.UGLFIRACaHpGGIDEEv-4IIdLfCGXT62X1vYx7keNMyc`

If I Copy the above JWT token and paste it in https://jwt.io/ then the actual information is showing like this

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFzIE.png)

I want to encrypt the JWT token with no one can access my information in Web Api. So, I want to use any encryption algorithm, If so please provide me proper solution

Here is my Startup.cs file to authorize JWT Token.

```
        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: While JWT allows encrypting the token, it is often not necessary because the connection is already secured with TLS/SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why exactly do you think that it is a problem that someone can see this information? If you are using JWT for authentication, then it's only the user who was just authenticated will get this token and it probably contains the information about this user. So it does not hurt for a user to be able to see information about himself.

Most importantly the token is mac'ed so that no one can forge it and pretend to be another user and that should be sufficient.

And as mentioned in the comments you should be using TLS anyway, so it's encrypted in the transition.

Comment: In my JWT Token i want to store information like UserID. So that somebody can get it and hack

Comment: "Somebody" is only the user that has this Id or someone with physical access to the machine if you use TLS, so it is not a problem. Knowing UserId is not a problem either (unless you have other more important vulnerabilities), so it's not problem to use just the identity from SQL server e.g. The problem is if you don't check the user input and access rights when you have a request. Another thing is that even if the userId is known to the user, they won't be able to CHANGE it in the JWT since it's mac'ed.